# Dirac distribution and Sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

I see the conclusion that

> $\delta_{x_{0}} \in H^{s}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ if and only if $s<-n/2$, where $ H^{s}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right) $ is Sobolev space.

from many places, and the hint is polar coordinates or Sobolev embedding. How can I use the hint to prove the conclusion? Thanks very much.

Comment: You want to show that the map $\delta_{x_0}: H^{-s}(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \ f \mapsto f(x_0)$ is continuous. If you can control the norm of $H^{-s}$ by some $C^{0,\alpha}$ norm, then clearly we get the continuity. For $-s>n/2$ you can use the Gagliardo–Nirenberg–Sobolev inequality so get exactly this control.

Comment: That gives the "if" part. For the other use that there are function with finite $H^s$-norm $s \leq n/2$ that are unbounded.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to also adress the other direction. To be a bit more precise, we should say that a priori we can only define $\delta_{x_0}$ for - say - continuous functions (otherwise it is not clear, what $f(x_0)$ should mean as we are working with equivalence classes). Then the question is, whether or not we can continuously extend the functional to all of $H^{-s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The nice hint of @AdriánGonzález-Pérez then tells us how to show that we cannot extend our functional continuously.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use Fourier transform. The Fourier transform of $\delta_{x_0}$ is $y\mapsto e^{-ix_0\cdot y}$. Therefore
$$
\|\delta_0\|_{H^s}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |e^{-ix_0\cdot y}|^2\,(1+|y|^2)^{s}\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (1+|y|^2)^{s}\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
which is finite if and only if $s<-n/2$.