# Norm of Dirac delta derivative in negative order Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$, and consider the negative order Sobolev space $W^{-k,p}$. Given $p>1$, a distribution $f$ is in $W^{-k,p}$ if and only if, by definition of the space,
$$
f=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}D^\alpha f_\alpha
$$
see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096093/sobolev-spaces-with-negative-exponent). They also state that the associated norm is defined as $$\inf\left\{\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}\|f_\alpha\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\right\}$$

Now from what I understand, $\delta'$, the derivative of the Dirac delta distribution is in $W^{-1,p}$ but I have trouble working out its associated norm ? Similarly what then should be the norm of the Heaviside Theta distribution ?

Comment: Perhaps I should take $\alpha=-1$ and $f_{-1}=1$ in which case $\delta'$ has the norm $\|1\|_{L^p(\Omega)}$ which is finite if $\Omega$ is bounded. I would like to treat Heaviside Theta the same way so both have the same norm. Is that right ?

Comment: $\delta'$ is not in $W^{-1,p}$ but in some $W^{-2,p}$ for appropriate $p$ (not too large)

Comment: @daw yes ok I was mistaken, but so what is the norm of $\delta'$ in $W^{-2,p}$ ? And for $\Theta$?

Comment: $\delta\in W^{s,p}$ when $s<-d(1-1/p)$. $\delta'$ is then in $W^{s-1,p}$. You can look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3636148/dirac-distribution-and-sobolev-spaces/3637833#3637833 for the simpler case $p=2$.

Comment: Ok I get it now, I think @LL 3.14 has answered the question. Thank you